# Django: Update multiple objects with regex

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to remove `'blog/'` substring from `slug` field of multiple objects according to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) and [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#query-expressions) docs:

```
>>> import re
>>> from django.db.models import F
>>> p = re.compile('blog/')
>>> Blog.objects.update(slug=p.sub('', F('slug')))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

I tried to add `str()` to the last string, and it passes without errors:

```
>>> Blog.objects.update(slug=p.sub('', str(F('slug'))))
```

but it inserts `(DEFAULT: )` into `slug` field for all objects.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To update multiple objects at once in Django with regular expressions over a queryset you can use a [Func expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions) to access regex functions in your database:

```py
django.db.models import F, Func, Value


pattern = Value(r'blog(/?)')  # the regex
replacement = Value(r'new-blog-slug\1')  # replacement string
flags = Value('g')  # regex flags

Blog.objects.update(
    slug=Func(
        models.F('slug'),
        pattern, replacement, flags,
        function='REGEXP_REPLACE',
        output_field=models.TextField(),
    )
)
```

Check your DB vendor documentation for details and specific functions support.

Use raw strings `r''` in `pattern` and `replacement` to avoid having to escape the backslashes.

Reference matched substrings in `replacement` using `\n` with `n` from 1 to 9.

You can use `F` expressions to provide `pattern`, `replacement` and `flags` from fields of each instance:

```py
pattern = F('pattern_field')
replacement = F('replacement_field')
flags = F('flags_field')
```

You can also use the `Func` expression to make annotations.

Currently there is an [open pull request](https://github.com/django/django/pull/12438) to add regular expressions database functions in Django. Once merged you will probably have `RegexpReplace`, `RegexpStrIndex` and `RegexpSubstr` function expressions available under `django.db.models.functions` to make your code more concise and have a single API unified across DB vendors.

Comment: Exactly. The only solution that updates db in one query with regexp.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. The update is done completely within the database, so it must be something translatable to SQL, which your code isn't. You'll need to iterate through and update:

```
for blog in Blog.objects.filter(slug__startswith='blog/'):
    blog.slug = blog.slug.replace('blog/', '')
    blog.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works. But why do you say I can't do that? [update() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) is converted directly into SQL and it doesn't run `save()` methods or emits `post_save` signal - exactly what I need, because I don't want extra jobs done by `save()` and signals. I tested my code and it works untill I added `re.sub()`.

Comment: Well yes exactly, the `re.sub()` is Python so it can't be converted to SQL.

Comment: It is sad to hear. This code was iterating 13K record for about 15 minutes. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: It is possible to do the regex replace at database level, I added a answer with further explanation.

Answer (score 2):

A little late but for those who need a solution today 
**Note:New in Django 2.1.**

class Replace

Usage example from [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/):

```
>>> from django.db.models import Value
>>> from django.db.models.functions import Replace
>>> Author.objects.create(name='Margaret Johnson')
>>> Author.objects.create(name='Margaret Smith')
>>> Author.objects.update(name=Replace('name', Value('Margaret'), Value('Margareth')))
2
>>> Author.objects.values('name')
<QuerySet [{'name': 'Margareth Johnson'}, {'name': 'Margareth Smith'}]>
```

Comment: Nice! 18K records in 1.113 seconds! Choosing this as accepted answer.

Comment: Using `Replace` is simple and fits the example posted in the question, but the answer doesn't cover the question completely because `Replace` doesn't support regular expressions. I posted an answer with the solution I found to get regex support.

Comment: @LuisSolis I regret to have downvoted you answer, it provides a solution for the example posted in the question and includes references that point to regex support. It seems I can't revert it, my apologies.