# How can I use regex in django's Replace function

Tags: python, django, django-3.1

I'm trying to update all urls in my query by using django's `update` and `Replace` function using regex.
Here's what I've tried so far but it seems like django's `Value` expression did not recognize my regex.

```
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Replace

Foo.objects.filter(
    some_url__iregex=r'^\/some-link\/\d+\/').update(
    some_url=Replace(
        'some_url', Value(r'^\/some-link\/\d+\/'),
        Value('/some-link/')))
```

My goal is to remove all numbers after `/some-link/` (e.g. `/some-link/55/test` to just `/some-link/test`)

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get the `Replace` function from Django working, but I was able to use the Function for `REGEXP_REPLACE` detailed in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68402017/3056056